# Adding function to addToBackStack()

Tags: android, back-stack

I'm using an OnClickListener to do a fragment replacement. I'm toggling 3 LinearLayouts to 'GONE' within the OnClickListener also.

I would like to add a function to set the 3 LinearLayouts back to VISIBLE when the back button is pressed. The fragments swap back, but the LinearLayouts don't change their state.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
final OnClickListener swapFragments = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (myAdapter.isEmpty() != true) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();

            FragmentTwoTop ftt = new FragmentTwoTop();
            FragmentTwoBottom ftb = new FragmentTwoBottom();

            ft.replace(R.id.leftTopHolder, ftt, "fragmenttwotop");
            ft.replace(R.id.leftBottomtHolder, ftb, "fragmenttwobottom");

            layoutOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutThree.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            ft.addToBackStack("swapfragments");

            ft.commit();

        } else {

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a listener to the backstack: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#addOnBackStackChangedListener(android.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener)

It will be called any time "something" is added or removed from/to the backstack.

You can then check the type of the class of the fragment (or maybe your holding the current fragment in a class - your Activity - variable) to decide if it's necessary to execute your animation.

The method in which you manage the layouts could simply check the visibility (`getVisibility`) and if it's `VISIBLE` then set to `GONE`, if it's `GONE` set to `VISIBLE`.